# how to retrieve multiple result from mysql and input each result into an html element

Tags: php, jquery, html

i want to retrieve 3 information from the database based on the `ID` number input. when i type number **5** in an `<input id="id">` html markup. get the `name`, `age`, `email` of the associated number and insert it on a dedicate `<input>` box for each result

how do i get the multiple result from my query and then input the result on my `<input>` markup

```
<input id="name">  //insert name from db
<input id="age">  //insert name from db
<input id="email">  //insert name from db
```

below is my code, where it only fetches the `name` from the database and input it on an `<input id="name">` markup.

**My Jquery**

```
var id = $('input#id').val(); //get value of input box
$.post('./ajax/getdata.php', {id: id}, function(data) //pass this to getdata.php
{
$('input#name').val(data);

}
```

**MY getdata.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) === true && empty($_POST['id']) === false) 
{
require '../connect.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `memberNo` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id'])). "' ";
$result = $db->query($query);

   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
   echo $row['firstname'];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since your `id` must be unique, you don't need to do a `while` loop.

And since you are returning an ajax call, JSON might be the best data format (and the default for jQuery).

So in your getdata.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) === true && empty($_POST['id']) === false) 
{
    require '../connect.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `memberNo` = '"
            . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id'])). "' ";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc()
    // setting the appropriate content type
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo (json_encode($row));
}
```

And you process this in the `success` callback:

```
var id = $('input#id').val(); //get value of input box
$.post('./ajax/getdata.php', {"id": id}, function(data)
{
    $('input#name').val(data.firstname);
    $('input#age').val(data.age);
    $('input#email').val(data.email);
}
```